# I have a JSON file in which want to read the data but i cant seem to just display one column of its data. Any idea how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This is the JSON file i currently have and i only want to display the rdid column. I've just started learning node for a few days and i don't really know what i am doing.

**data**

```json
[
    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r8v9ee", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r8v9ee", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r8v9ee", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"}
]
```

**code**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function execute1() {
    while (true) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('data.json');
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fileStream,
            
        });
        
        for await (var line of rl) {
            var rid = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(line));
            var x = Object.assign(line);
            var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
            //console.log(rdi);
            console.log(y.rdid);            
        }
    }
}

execute1();
```

Comment: You need to give more details. In what context do you mean 'display', how are you accessing this file within your code, and what have you tried.

Comment: just include your file reading code in your question

Comment: please confirm the data of your json file, is it correct, do you really have `;` in the end of your json file?

Comment: @RaghavGarg no i don't, stackoverflow wasnt letting me post so i tried putting it to see if it helps.

Comment: and why the infinite while loop? do you want to process this file every 1s?

Comment: This is supposed to process every 15 mins but i speed it up to skip the waiting

Comment: and also if i update the json while it is running, will my output change as well ? or will it just display the same output.

Comment: As stated below, the data.json file isn't valid JSON. Are you able to amend it's contents for your application, or is it an external data source you can't control?

Comment: @MunkyJunky I think OP confirmed that this a JSON file and contains valid json data.

Comment: @MunkyJunky its a valid JSON now after using the link provided to edit and validate

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a JSON file, you will need to read the whole file in one go, something like this

```js
// fs.readFile is function that supports only callback, because of which we will need to promisify it.
function readFile(file_name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(file_name, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

async function execute(file_name) {
    try {
        const file_data = await readFile(file_name);
        const records = JSON.parse(file_data);
        return records.map(single_record => single_record.rdid);
    }
    catch(e) {
         // error handling
    }
}

execute("data.json").then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: @Garuda you can add the functionality of while loop according to your need

Comment: i tried removing the commas from the end of every line but it became and invalid JSON file.

Comment: yeah, because that is not the right way to read a json file. you will never be sure if the current line you are reading is valid or not after removing some chars.

Comment: i tried this new one but i dont know why the output is empty

Comment: I have tried it but the output still says undefined.

Comment: oh golly it works now, thank you so much @Raghav Garg

Answer (score 0):

That isn't valid JSON. See https://jsonlint.com/ for a tool to help you see if it is or is not.

You would, at least, need to wrap your “rows” of data in a [ ]
you need to write JSON file as arry of objects like

```
[
 {},{},... etc.
]
```

Comment: it could be a possibility that this a log file and each line in itself is a valid json, maybe that's why OP is reading the file line by line.

Comment: @Tom Harvey is right,  no matter where it comes from it should be validated first.

Comment: I've edited and validated it but the result is still the same